# What does IconSource mean in react-native-paper?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

So, I was looking at react-native-paper v5 documentation , and icon has property IconSource for icon in SegmentedButtons? What does it mean? Is it a simple

```js
 <MaterialIcon name="home" color="black" size={25}/>
```

or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

`SegmentedButton` does not have a property called `IconSource` the property is `icon` as you can see in [docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/SegmentedButtons/#props) :

> Type: {
>  value: string;
>  icon?: IconSource;
>  disabled?: boolean;
>  accessibilityLabel?: string;
>  checkedColor? string;
>  uncheckedColor?: string;
>  onPress?: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
>  label?: string;
>  showSelectedCheck?: boolean;
>  style?: StyleProp;
>  testID?: string; }

property `icon`:

> icon: icon to display for the item

so `IconSource` is just the type of the value that the property `icon` should recieve.

I don't really know what is this type even in docs if you click on `Type`: [IconSource](https://callstack.github.io/docs/icons) it redirects to this 404 not found page!

But in this [example](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/IconButton/#usage) using `IconButton` component that also has the same property `icon` of type `IconSource` you can see that it is equal to "camera" so it should display the camera icon.

```js
<IconButton
    icon="camera" // <-- this line
    iconColor={MD3Colors.error50}
    size={20}
    onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
/>
```